# raise exceptions to flag a successful connection as a failure based upon response data

Tags: locust

In  some cases my locust test makes a successful connection to the endpoint, but the data returned is not expected.  How do I raise an  exception so Locust knows this request should be considered a failure, even though the connection to the endpoint succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use catch_response=True, a with-block and a call to resp.failure() as documented here:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#manually-controlling-if-a-request-should-be-considered-successful-or-a-failure